# anomaly data in dygraphs - how do I handle it?

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I have some charts where there are a few anomalies in the data.

It skews the charts & makes them unreadable (unless you zoom).

Is there a way I can click on an anomaly data point & effectively hide it, so the rest of the chart becomes usable?

Here is an example of the problem:

[image]

Comment: You may try smoothing the data with one of these algorithms?http://stackoverflow.com/a/36933276/1273587

Comment: Thank you for your response! Ideally, I still want to show the data on the chart (incase it is a legitimate anomaly that needs to be analysed). However, the user should be able to decide to discount that anomaly. Not sure it is possible

Comment: Could you use a valueRange declaration when creating the graph? Something like `valueRange: [-0.2, 0.2]`