# Sensor value interpretation

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am currently trying to understand the sensor values I get from code similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999290/compass-and-accelerometer-precision).
The yaw/azimuth value seems to be okay. The problem is the pitch value, because I get -90° when the device is upright and tilting back and forward lead to the same values. 
Lets say i tilt by 45° forward - the value is -45°, so its the same like tilting the device 45° backward. 
Like this I cannot determine the device pitch in 360°.
Can somebody help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorListener.html:

> All values are angles in degrees.
>
> values[0]: Azimuth, rotation around the Z axis (0<=azimuth<360). 0 = North, 90 = East, 180 = South, 270 = West
>
> values[1]: Pitch, rotation around X axis (-180<=pitch<=180), with positive values when the z-axis moves toward the y-axis.
>
> values[2]: Roll, rotation around Y axis (-90<=roll<=90), with positive values when the z-axis moves toward the x-axis.

Note that this definition of yaw, pitch and roll is different from the traditional definition used in aviation where the X axis is along the long side of the plane (tail to nose).

So Pitch -180°  - 180° instead of 0° - 360°. The difference is forward shows -45° and backward should show 45°, right?

Comment: Thanks TryTryAgain! The problem is, that forward and backwards it shows -45°, so there is no difference.

Comment: What values do you get when going around in a complete 360°? Does it ever show you the positive side of 180?

Comment: Yes there are positive values. Up = -90°, Up 45° forward = -45°, Up 45° backward = -45°, Down = 90°, Down 45° forward = 45°, Down 45° backward = 45°. Hope this is clearly written ;-) So there is noch 180 degree...